# Need a login dialogue to open on pageload event

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have searched high and low but I cannot get this simple thing to work.

All I want to do is have a dialogue popup open when the homepage loads.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [Dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/UeHGp/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<!--<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">Test Dialog Box</div>-->
    <div id="dialog" title="Google">
    <IFRAME id="frame" style="border: 0px;" SRC="www.google.com" width="100%" height = "100%" >
</div>

</body>
```

---

Different solution

try [this](http://www.webinone.net/demo/ajax_login/)..if this ok..

---

Different solution

Try the [Modal Dialog](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/pages/docs-dialogs.html)..Any page can be presented as a modal dialog by adding the data-rel="dialog" attribute to the page anchor link.

---

> $(document).delegate('div[data-role=dialog]', 'pageinit', function() {})

Comment: thanks for the quick response, i see your example pops up a div from the same page, any chance you can show me how to pull in an external file?

Comment: the dialog that i want to 'popup' is a login screen, which is a page and not a div.

Comment: hi, i dont like using iframes, this is not the ideal solution.

Comment: its not the unique solution..there can be multiply way to solve the problem

Comment: I want to open a dialogue box on my index page, the dialogue box will get its content from a file within the app, called login.html.

Take a look here (home screen): http://webtrendz.co.uk/client-demo/lab/ipad-framework/

login screen: http://webtrendz.co.uk/client-demo/lab/ipad-framework/login.html

Comment: hmm not quite, i can do the popup on a link, but i want one on page load

Comment: thanks for doing that sobingt, i cant quite see how the code would openthe login.html file as an overlay.

I have added a login link at top left of the site, when clicked this opens in a dialogue box.

I just want this dialogue to pop up on page load, without the user clicking the login link.

Any ideas?